# OS X SSH no route to host

Tags: macos, ssh, remote-login

I have enabled SSH on a Mac (running OS X 10.9).

When the machine first turns on and I run  `ssh 192.168.1.2` from my remote machine I get `no route to host`. Subsequently, if I were to login to my Mac, and then run SSH on the remote machine I am able to connect without issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: looks like you installed ssh daemon only for your user not global

Comment: "no route to host" suggests you were trying too soon, and your Mac hadn't finished booting and getting its DHCP leased IP address fully working. Trying pinging it while it's booting and wait until pings work before SSH'ing.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly configured sshd with your account instead of root.  `ls` the file and see if you or root owns it.  If it's you, use chown to switch it to root.

```
sudo chown root:wheel /etc/sshd_config (or some other file)
```

HTH